# Cómo Inhabilitar un boton bootstrap dentro de una tabla segun Fecha de unos de sus campos

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con bootgrid table la cual me carga datos y en su columna 4 está la fecha por cada registro. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que si la fecha que ésta tabla trae es pasada(menor) que la de hoy el boton que esta en acciones("confirmar") se deshabilite. Todo esto es por cada registro. El problema es que mi script me inhabilita todos los botones y si le cambio el operador ">" me habilita todo. No se cual es el error en mi script. Desde ya muchas Gracias.-

NOTA:
Estoy trayendo mis datos de una consulta mysql en la cual ya formateo la fecha con el formato dd-mm-YYY por eso en este script formateo la fecha en javascript al mismo formato.

Aqui mi script:

```
   $(document).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
 {
  var tablaturnos = $('#turnos_data');

  var hoy = new Date();
  var dd = String(hoy.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(hoy.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');  
  var yyyy = hoy.getFullYear();

   hoy = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;

console.log(hoy);

   var fechaFormulario ='';

 $('#turnos_data > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4)').each(function(){
  fechaFormulario = $(this).html() ;
 console.log(fechaFormulario);


     if (hoy <= fechaFormulario){
  
       tablaturnos.find(".confirmar").prop('disabled',false);
     } 
      else {
      tablaturnos.find(".confirmar").prop('disabled',true);
     }
 
  });
});
```

Comment: Saludos. Estas comparando cadenas de texto no propiamente fechas; te sugiero en tal caso tu formato sea Año-Mes-Día para realizar la comparación. Desde luego deberás realizar lo respectivo para cada variable (hoy y fechaFormulario) con que realizas la comparación.

Comment: Mejor aun, estas comparando cadenas de texto como si fueran numeros, lo cual propiamente NO lo son, es mas, tu mismo te encargas de que no sean numeros colocandole "-" en ciertas partes, de todas maneras las comparaciones de ese estilo deberian ser propiamente numeros y no cadenas de texto.

Comment: Prueba con `fechaFormulario = new Date($(this).text());` para comparar directamente objetos de fecha y deja `hoy` solo como fecha, eliminando la parte donde obtienes día, mes, año y lo conviertes a cadena.

Comment: La verdad es que fechaFormulario no es un string. Me da error cada vez que quiero parsearlo a Date un NaN o un "invalid date"

Comment: Haciendole un console.log a fechaFormulario me da una fecha formateada dd-mm-YYYY.  O sea es la que trae la sentencia mysql formateada ya con SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d-%m-%Y') as fecha

Comment: A la variable "hoy" si le estoy cambiando el formato de YYYY-mm-dd a dd-mm-YYYY ya que tiene que ser comparada con fechaFormulario la cual está como dije ya formateada (dd-mm-YYYY) desde la sentencia y es la que se ve en la tabla